# error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1 while installing mysqlclient

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, gcc, mysql-python

I am trying to install `mysqlclient` in OSX 10.7  but I get this compiler error from `gcc` no matter what I try. I am using Python3.6 to run the `setup.py` script for `mysqlclient`.

[image]

Comment: What version of gcc are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install XCode. The error message says that you don't have GCC in your mac. It will get installed as part of XCode